# Evaluate $\int^1_0\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate $\int^1_0\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}\ dx$

This seems pretty simple: $$\int^1_0\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}\ dx\\=\int^1_0\sqrt{(x-1)^2}\ dx\\=\int^1_0x-1\ dx\\=\frac{x^2}{2}-x\\=-\frac12$$ I don't think I made any mistakes in my calculations - except that I don't understand why I got a negative number. Looking at the graph it seems that it should be positive - why am I getting a negative answer? [image]

Comment: Did you realize that your graph shows $y=x^2-2x+1$, not $y=\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner whoops:) Fixed

Comment: now you can see that $\sqrt {x^2-2x+1}$ is positive, whereas $x-1$ is negative, when $0\le x\le 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you have

$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2} = |x - 1| \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

For $0 \le x \le 1$, this would be $1 - x$ instead of the $x - 1$ you used.

Comment: Why the absolute value?

Comment: Is it because the squared term makes negatives impossible?

Comment: $\sqrt{}\;$ denotes the positive square root

Comment: @Burt When taking square roots, both negative and positive values are possible. However, normally, as J.W. Tanner's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490670/evaluate-int1-0-sqrtx2-2x1-dx/3490673#comment7177863_3490673) states, the square root symbol normally means the positive value is what intended when it's used in equations. Note your graph uses the positive value. It is because of this issue that your graph and your calculations don't agree with each other.

Answer (score 3):

Note that when $x\in[0,1]$, $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}=\sqrt{(x-1)^2}=\lvert x-1\rvert=-(x-1)$